# How can I control the order of execution for TestSuites?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, testcase

I have a number of test suites that make use of the [Test::Unit::TestCase](http://search.cpan.org/~mcast/Test-Unit-0.25/lib/Test/Unit/TestCase.pm) package and since it is a parallel environment I need to modify them to ensure that one [TestSuite](http://search.cpan.org/~mcast/Test-Unit-0.25/lib/Test/Unit/TestSuite.pm) does not start until another has completed. Based upon the documentation it appears that there is a way to control the order of the suite execution:

> If you need to specify the test order, you can do one of the
>   following:
>
> - Provide a suite() method    which returns a Test::Unit::TestSuite.

However, there don't appear to be any examples of how to do this. Is this actually possible and if so how should it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tests are insightful.

```
$ cpanm --look Test::Unit::TestCase
$ ack -l 'sub suite' t
```

> [`t/tlib/SuiteTest.pm`](https://metacpan.org/source/MCAST/Test-Unit-0.25/t/tlib/SuiteTest.pm)
>
> `t/tlib/AssertTest.pm`
>
> `t/tlib/AllTests.pm`

Comment: So if I'm reading this correctly (still new with Perl) the `suite()` function is creating a new `suite` object which contains a number of tests that are being generated by the indicated functions which creates the test suites to be run on the fly?